# Magnetic Field Strength Measurement at Extreme Temperatures

Tags: magnetic-fields, experimental-physics, temperature

I have just been given a project at work and we are magnetically stress testing DUTs at extreme temperatures going from -40 Degrees Celsius to 200 Degrees Celsius. I need to come up with a way that we can read the magnetic field strength while we are testing. I have tried looking into a hall sensor but I would need it in die form and can't find it anywhere, especially in the temperature range given. Do you have any suggestions? I only started as a Co-Op student and am drawing blanks as I don't have much experience in this field.

Comment: Does the sensor have to be at that temperature, or just the device under test?

Comment: the DUT will be going into ovens which will be testing in the range  given above to stress test them and while they are in the ovens we need to be able to tell the magnetic field strength in order to know that all the devices on the burn in board are the same, so ya the sensor will be at those temperatures.

Comment: So I'm assuming that the magnetic field is generated by the DUT? Or is it applied externally? Would measuing/monitoring the field external to the oven to show it is changing (or unchanged) be sufficient?

Comment: we have a magnet incorporated into the package that we have created that can be adjusted to be static or rotating, so we need to be monitoring the the magnetic field while in the ovens as we need to know what it is when it is -40 and 200 which are not possible to reach outside the oven.